# running tests in libgdx using intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, libgdx

my team and myself are creating an app using libgdx, and we keep some of our data in a json file. Nothing special. the file is kept in "android/assets/data/cards.json", so the Gdx.files.internal command can find it easily in android (naturally) and when running the desktop version (after changing the working directory). 
Problem is, when running the tests in intellij the working directory change doesn't apply, so it can't find it. I tried to make a copy of said file into the core project. so I have these 2 ways of reading the file:

`public static final String cardsJsonFilePath = "data/cards.json";
    /**** at a later method ****/
    byte[] encoded = (Gdx.files.internal(cardsJsonFilePath)).readBytes();
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(cardsJsonFilePath));`

the first assignment works in every configuration except the tests (which recieve a null from GDX.files.internal) and the second one works as long as I keep the copy of the data folder in the core directory, and not on android (since Files and Paths appearantly do not exist in android).
also, the latter is a rather poor solution since it forces me to keep an updated copy of the file for tests sake.

TL ; DR
I have an asset that I want my tests to access in intellij, and I want it to work with libgdx.files.internal or some other android friendly solution.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can specify the working directory in the settings of the IntelliJ run configuration for your tests. Doesn't this help?

Comment: actually I haven't managed to define it for my tests, only for my application run. or I would have done it straight away. but it turns out I was wrong when diagnosing my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

so, I found out the answer to my own question, so if you have a similar problem I hope this helps.
I was wrong when I suspected that the null pointer exception was due to not finding the file.
the reason for the exception is that the Gdx class is not properly initialized when not run in a proper application context (for example, when used for a test). so the null was not the result of the internal method, but Gdx.files itself was null.

in short, you can't just use libgdx library methods when you feel like, it's a framework, not a library.

the workaround we used was this:

    `byte[] encoded;
    if (Gdx.files == null)
        encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(cardsJsonFilePath));
    else
        encoded = (Gdx.files.internal(cardsJsonFilePath)).readBytes();
    return new String(encoded);`

so the andoird application doesn't crash because it never uses the files and paths part of the code (I'm somewhat surprised that it compiles, but meh. not gonna argue with a good thing, right? ) and the tests can still use it in place of the null Gdx.files field. so everybody wins!

have fun building (and testing!) your games! :)